# Mailchimp RSS loop, get index

Tags: rss, mailchimp

In RSSITEMS loop, I would like to find a way to get an index variable (0,1,2,3,4 for 5 items) so I can display items at different places. I couldn't find a way to do that, so I passed a variable in  RSS tag, but I can't access it with conditional tags  like *|IF:RSSITEM:COMMENTS_URL = 1|* (it simply doesn't work but I can print the variable without problem (1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mailchimp support told me it's not possible. Instead, I modified the feed to include 1 item which is HTML with my multiple feeds parsed. I now realize I could have used *|FEED:...|* merge tag with a standard campaign.

Comment: How would the `FEED` merge tag have helped?

Comment: What I mean is that instead of looping rss items in Mailchimp template, I process them before sending the final HTML output to MC. The Feed merge tag would still be used as a trigger for renewed content (RSS campaign).